# plotting points in 3d surface using x,y,z coordinates

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I need to plot some points in 3d surface based on x,y,z coordiantes values in a file named as test.dat

test.dat file contains

---

### At-No                     X           Y           Z

```
 6                   3.532210   -2.171743    0.921140
 7                   1.164869   -1.418981    0.782133
 1                   2.454732    2.332989   -0.907213
 6                  -3.246376   -1.047325   -0.602590
 6                  -2.620684    0.053348   -0.013310
 6                  -4.569969   -1.249720   -0.617858
 6                  -3.436335    1.003953    0.597094
 1                  -5.328079   -0.323336   -0.025131
```

First value indicates At-no(Atomic number) , second value indicates x coordinates value, 3rd value indicate y coordinates values and finally 4th value indicate z coordinate value.

I tried Gnuplot

```
splot "test.dat" u 1:2:3 ps variable pt 7
```

but it give a blank screen .
I want to display points on 3d surface.... Points with At-no 6 display in red color and 7 with blue and 1 with green.
Is it possible to display points like this

Thanks in Advance................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional plotting.

```
splot 'data.txt' u ($1==6 ? $2:1/0):3:4 title 'At-no 6' w points pt 7, \
      'data.txt' u ($1==7 ? $2:1/0):3:4 title 'At-no 7' w points pt 7, \
      'data.txt' u ($1==1 ? $2:1/0):3:4 title 'At-no 1' w points pt
```

This creates

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply and response. The above is working and Thanks a lot....... I need one more help how it can be saved in our system and how can we call it from a PHP interface.

Comment: You can use plotly library which is an open source tool for plotting 3D Surface and Scatter Plots in various languages. **https://plot.ly/**